# Unable to JOIN and get the final query

Tags: sql, ado.net

I'm having this following situation for which i'm unable to form a sql query. Please help me with this.

```
create table student(
    studentName varchar(50)
);

Insert into student values('abc');
Insert into student values('mnop');
Insert into student values('xyz');
Insert into student values('pqrs');

create table workAssigned (
    topic varchar(50),
    creator varchar(50),
    reviewer varchar(50),
    creationCount decimal(4,2)
    reviewCount decimal(4,2)
);

insert into workAssigned values('algebra','abc','mnop',1.25,0.75);
insert into workAssigned values('geometry','mnop','xyz',1.5,0.25);
insert into workAssigned values('algorithms','mnop','xyz',1.5,1.5);
insert into workAssigned values('derivative','xyz','abc',0.25,1);
```

final output reqiured is:

```
StudentName    NumberOfWorkDone    Effort
abc                    2            2.25                 
mnop                   3            3.75
xyz                    3              2
pqrs                  NUll         NULL
```

Where NumberOfWorkDone is SUM of creator and Reviewer, and 
      Effort is SUM of creationCount and reviewCount

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`, `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select studentName,NumberOfWorkDone,Effort
From student as A
Left Join
(
    Select creator,count(creator) as NumberOfWorkDone,sum(creationCount) as Effort
    From
    (
        Select creator,creationCount
        from workAssigned as A
        Union all
        Select reviewer,reviewCount from workAssigned
    )as A
    Group by creator
)as B
On A.studentName=B.creator
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `Group By`, `Join` and `CASE` with [Aggregate functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173454.aspx),

```
SELECT studentName,
SUM(CASE WHEN W.creator = S.studentName OR S.studentName = W.reviewer THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) AS NumberOfWorkDone,
SUM(CASE WHEN W.creator = S.studentName THEN W.creationCount WHEN S.studentName = W.reviewer THEN W.REVIEWCOUNT ELSE NULL END) AS Efforts
FROM student S
LEFT JOIN workAssigned W
ON S.studentName = W.creator OR S.studentName = W.reviewer
GROUP BY studentName
```

I have added `NULL` into Case statement for else part as your output was showing `NULL` but I think it would be better if you would replace that with `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
 (select count(col_X) as F, col_X
  from 
 (select creator as col_X from workAssigned
  UNION ALL
 select reviewer as col_X from workAssigned) AS A
  group by col_X) as E
left join
 (select A, sum(B)
  from
 (select creator as A, creationCount as B
  from workAssigned
  UNION ALL
  select revieweras A, reviewCount as B
  from workAssigned) as C
  group by A) as D
on E.F = D.A
```